Next.js - Dynamically change Body's background image based on screen size
I'm using Next.js 14.2.12 and I'm trying to create a login page with different background images for the <body> element based on screen size. Here's the basic structure of my src/app/login/page.tsx component:
"use client";

const Login: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <p>Some text</p>
    </>
  );
};

export default Login;

Is there a built-in way in Next.js to achieve this? Or do I need to use CSS media queries and JavaScript to dynamically update the background image? If so, how can I do this efficiently without affecting performance?
I am working with the following four screen sizes and I want to apply four different images of PNG format.


You can use a media query as you ask, or you can refer to that document if you use tailwind CSS. BTW, wouldn't it be nice to provide an example of what kind of image you want to show under what conditions?

@NINE Thank you for your replay. As you can see I have added a screenshot of the screen sizes. I have 4 png images, one for each of the screens.
